# Google+ 'share' not detecting the language setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-plus

I've been trying to add the plus one button on our company's product page. We have a multi - subdomain website which has language translated content for that particular subdomain. The user's language preference is remembered via cookies.

Now when when I hit the +1 button, and try to share the page on google+ I do not see the translated description come up on it. It somehow grabs the "English" description. When I try to look at my "MetaDescription" tag it is in the foreign language.

What I've been guessing is that google was trying to call the URL I was trying to share and crawling it instead of crawling the very page I was clicking the +1 button on. What would be the best way to make google detect the language setting on the page i want to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the API to load in the different languages, you should specify the `lang` in the config.  Do this BEFORE the plusone.js can load.  That should make the button and it's screens display with that language.

Here's an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>+1 Demo: Async render</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <g:plusone></g:plusone>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.___gcfg = {
        lang: 'zh-CN'
      };

      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, for the share part of it, can you be sure that when Google scrapes the page you're sharing that it is picking up the correct language?  Since the user agent Google is using might not specify a language, your page is being rendered to Google's scrapers as the default language.  Maybe you should have a canonical URL for each language for your page that google can scrape correctly.